# pandas groupby aggregate with keyword `key` not working in 1.01

Tags: python, pandas

Not sure if I messed up my environment somehow or it's the new version of `pandas`

I have this function that downsamples while maintaining the maximum absolute value:

```
def TH_downsample(df, Hz):
    return df.groupby(lambda x: x // (1/Hz) / Hz).max(key = abs)
```

It's worked previously (3.6) but with a new `python3.7` environment and `pandas` 1.0.1 I get:

```
File "...\groupby.py", line 1378, in f
    return self._cython_agg_general(alias, alt=npfunc, **kwargs)

TypeError: _cython_agg_general() got an unexpected keyword argument 'key'
```

(hope that's all correct, I hand-copied from an airgapped machine)

Has something been updated in `pandas` that breaks this?  Or is it more likely I messed up my environment?

EDIT:

This works:

```
def TH_downsample(df, Hz):
    return df.groupby(lambda x: x // (1/Hz) / Hz).agg(lambda x: max(x, key = abs))
```

So I'm mostly just wondering why it broke between versions.

Comment: Looks to me the problem is with `max`, not groupby. You could try this by assigning the groupby result to a variable and try max on that. See: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.max.html#pandas.Series.max, there's no mention of *key*

Comment: Don't think so.  Assigning `temp = np.groupby(..)` and `return temp.max(key = abs)` gives the same error on the `return` statement

Comment: And if there was some problem with the keyword it wouldn't have worked in `python3.6` unless something changed

Comment: There's two different "max". The Python max, which accepts key as a parameter and the pandas.series.max, which doesn't have this. Not sure why this used to work in your old environment, but you found a solution.

Comment: But `pandas.series.max` used to have it, which is why I'm asking a question.

Comment: Do you remember what version of pandas this used to work with? The same error occurred with 0.23.4 also